# How to create a custom header?

Tags: custom-header

I would like to create a custom header with a background image, as well as the ability to adjust the height and width of the header, and the ability to adjust the logo size. Here is my code:

```
header { background: url("http://996.0af.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Header204.png") center top no-repeat;
#header {
background: url(http://996.0af.myftpupload.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Header204.png") left top no-repeat;
#header {) no-repeat scroll left left!important;
height: 270px;
padding: 200;
}
#top .logo img {
width: 400px;
height: 340px;
}
#searchtop { display:none!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code formatting - in your question, there are unmatched quotes for your background image, as well as the second half of a background declaration for the second `#header` line.  Once you have fixed these issues, come on back and let us know if it worked or try and give some context i.e. a link or post a chunk of your page into JSFiddle/CodePen/etc. and/or indicate whether you are using an existing theme, any plugins you have, ...